# problems populating ListView in Notification

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a Notification.  When its expanded, I want it to display a ListView that I populate with data in real time.

Here's the Notification's expanded view (layout/notification_expanded.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right|top">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the layout of an individual row to append to it (layout/list_row.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Heading"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/heading"
        android:text="Content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Based on the examples I've seen, I need a RemoteViewFactory to produce RemoteViews that I
then attach to listViewWidget (described in the Notification's expanded view above)

public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

```
    private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> listItemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListProvider(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        populateListItem();
    }

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
    ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.heading);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, listItem.content);

    return remoteView;
}
```

}

and here is the Activity where my problems begin:

```
        RemoteViews expandedView =
                new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded);

        ListProvider lp = new ListProvider(this);

        //notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
        for (int ii = 0; ii< lp.getCount(); ii++) {
            notification.bigContentView = lp.getViewAt(ii);
        }
```

When the above code runs, I get the last element of my ArrayList displaying in the first element of my ListView.

I understand why - notification.bigContentView is the RemoteView that represents the notification when its expanded 
and I'm setting it to the RemoteView created from the last element in the ArrayList holding my data.

How do I change this so I append each element in the ArrayList to notification.bigContentView?  Is it possible to update the ListView with an ArrayAdapter in the typical fashion?

Comment: `I get the last element of my ArrayList displaying in the first element of my ListView.`. No not in your listview. You are not using the listview at all. You are only using the row layout as bigcontentview. So you will see two textviews.

Comment: `Is it possible to update the ListView with an ArrayAdapter in the typical fashion`. Don't know if it is possable but  an arrayadapter hould be the way i think.

Comment: Now that i found http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/ it looks as if you used that. Why not tell?

Comment: @greenapps - i didn't mention my use of laaptu because i didn't think it was relevant and google would indicate its use pretty quickly for anyone that was interested.

i'll experiment with the ArrayAdapter and report my results shortly

Comment: `i didn't think it was relevant` Of course that was relevant. Would have saved me time. Now in order to save you time you better read that article again as a normal array adapter will not do. You have to use the WidgetService as described there i think. Fidling around with it but could not get it to work yet. So keep me informed.

Comment: @greenapps - i apologize and won't make that mistake again.  i can post the exact code on pastebin or somewhere like that if you think it would help.  i thought about using WidgetService as laaptu described but was unsure.  isn't WidgetService unique to App Widgets?  i'm trying to use this with a Notification and wasn't sure if WidgetService was applicable.

Comment: `isn't WidgetService unique to App Widgets?` maybe. Thats to find out.

Comment: You have to use something like  expandedView.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listViewWidget, svcIntent); I see no possibility to set a 'normal' adapter.

Comment: @greenapps - i was wondering about that.  does svcIntent feed data into the RemoteView?  that's really the piece that's missing.  how do i get the data into the ListView in a RemoteView?

Comment: Just implement the whole setup of svcIntent as described. Anyhow it does not work here..

Comment: @greenapps - just so i'm clear, what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: `implement the whole setup of svcIntent as described.`

Comment: @greenapps - what problems did you encounter when you tried setting up the svcIntent?

Comment: My god. No one. It just did not work as said already.